# programmatically enable alt+space+m[ove] window mode where arrow keys can then be used to shift window in any desired direction

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a way to programmatically enable alt+space+m[ove] window mode where arrow keys can then be used to shift window in any desired direction?

I ask because like to create a global hotkey not requiring the three key sequence, e.g. alt+m[ove], to put the current active/foreground window into the state where you can use arrow keys [ and mouse ] to shift it around to desired location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selections from the window (system) menu generate a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message, which are normally handled by passing them through to `DefWindowProc`. Therefore you can simulate selections from this menu by sending that message to the window:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MOVE, 0);
```